# mayavi in python Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, mayavi

I installed `mayavi` in Anaconda using the command

```
conda.exe install mayavi
```

in Anaconda command prompt. Now when I close Spyder it doesn't open anymore. How do I fix this? I am using Windows.

Comment: Hi! Can you please give some more details? What do you mean "it doesn't open anymore"? Which version of Windows? Which version of Anaconda, and how did you install it?

Comment: When i click on the spyder logo , it fails to open. I tried it both on windows 7 and 8. I am using the 2.7 version of python. I tried to install Mayvi in it by using the command conda.exe install mayavi. It installed mayavi and my codes were running. But once i closed the spyder. The program fails to open again

Comment: OK, is there any error message or any indication why Spyder doesn't open? How did you install Anaconda? What if you try to start Spyder from the command line?

Comment: I dont see any error. The spyder simply doesnt starts. While installing mayavi, it had downgraded certain packages. whith the following message. The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    numexpr:      2.5-np110py27_0    --> 2.4.4-np19py27_0 
    numpy:        1.10.4-py27_0      --> 1.9.3-py27_1     
    scikit-learn: 0.17.1-np110py27_0 --> 0.16.1-np19py27_0
    scipy:        0.17.0-np110py27_0 --> 0.16.0-np19py27_0 After that spyder doesnt starts even after updating conda.

Comment: What if you open a command window and type `spyder`? How did you install Anaconda originally? What if you uninstall mayavi and update everything, then try opening spyder again?

Comment: I have the same experiences. Mayavi is really a mess and I stopped using it. conda update --all however helped me to be back running after a wasted day.

Comment: I got rid of mayavi eventually. I think i will need to stick with matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

I want to show my solution for that problem :
My OS = Windows 10 - 64-bit
Python 2.7.12 (Anaconda2 4.2.0 64-bit)
Package Mayavi version 4.4.0

After installation of that package Mayavi (with Anaconda Navigator Beta -> Environments), Spyder couldn't be opened again (as mentioned in your question).
Then I tried to open Spyder with a Command Prompt and I could read that the problem occured with the Package Pandas version 0.18.1.

Solution found : I downgraded the Package Pandas with its version 0.17.1.

Now Spyder works fine and I'm able to execute the examples found in Mayavi's folder.