# Installing Mayavi into Anaconda

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, mayavi

I want to install Mayavi into my anaconda installation for that I ran the following commands, but got an error message I am not sure how to deal with:

```
user@Kubuntu:~$ source activate myenv
(myenv)user@Kubuntu:~$ conda install mayavi
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda-client (target=anaconda-client-1.6.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - anaconda-client (target=anaconda-client-1.6.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> pytz
  - anaconda-client (target=anaconda-client-1.6.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> requests *|>=2.9.1
  - behave (target=behave-1.2.5-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> parse >=1.6.3
  - behave (target=behave-1.2.5-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 3.5*
  - clyent (target=clyent-1.2.2-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - cycler (target=cycler-0.10.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - cycler (target=cycler-0.10.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> six
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.3-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> freetype 2.4*
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.3-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> numpy 1.10*|1.11*|1.5*|1.6*|1.7*|1.8*|1.9*
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.3-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> pyparsing *|1.5.6|2.0.1|2.0.3
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.3-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> pyqt 4.*|5.*
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.3-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.3-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> pytz
  - mayavi -> numpy *|1.7*|1.8*|1.9*
  - mayavi -> pyqt 4.*
  - mayavi -> python 2.7*
  - mayavi -> setuptools
  - numpy (target=numpy-1.11.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*
  - pandas (target=pandas-0.19.2-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> numpy 1.10*|1.11*|1.6*|1.7*|1.8*|1.9*
  - pandas (target=pandas-0.19.2-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - pandas (target=pandas-0.19.2-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> pytz                                                                                                                                             
  - pandas (target=pandas-0.19.2-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> scipy                                                                                                                                            
  - parse (target=parse-1.6.6-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 3.5*                                                                                                                                              
  - parse_type (target=parse_type-0.3.4-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> parse >=1.6                                                                                                                                    
  - parse_type (target=parse_type-0.3.4-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 3.5*                                                                                                                                    
  - parse_type (target=parse_type-0.3.4-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> six                                                                                                                                            
  - pip (target=pip-9.0.1-py35_1.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*                                                                                                                                                  
  - pip (target=pip-9.0.1-py35_1.tar.bz2) -> wheel                                                                                                                                                        
  - py (target=py-1.4.32-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*                                                                                                                          
  - pyparsing (target=pyparsing-2.1.4-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*                                                                                                             
  - pyqt (target=pyqt-5.6.0-py35_1.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*                                                                                                                       
  - pytest (target=pytest-3.0.5-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*                                                                                                                   
  - python 3.5*                                                                                                                                                                                           
  - python-dateutil (target=python-dateutil-2.6.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*                                                                                                 
  - python-dateutil (target=python-dateutil-2.6.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> six                                                                                                                                  
  - pytz (target=pytz-2016.10-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*                                                                                                                     
  - pyyaml (target=pyyaml-3.12-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*                                                                                                                    
  - requests (target=requests-2.12.4-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - scipy (target=scipy-0.18.1-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> numpy 1.10*|1.11*|1.5*|1.6*|1.7*|1.8*|1.9*
  - scipy (target=scipy-0.18.1-np111py35_1.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - setuptools (target=setuptools-27.2.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - sip (target=sip-4.18-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - six (target=six-1.10.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - wheel (target=wheel-0.29.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

The question [mayavi in python Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38766293/4533188) is about a different error and on Windows, not Linux.

What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the conda package is for Python 2.7 and you have python 3.5. Search for a fitting package at https://anaconda.org/search?q=mayavi. There you find the package  conda install -c menpo mayavi=4.5.0 which you can install with `conda install -c menpo mayavi=4.5.0` and which should work with Python 3.5.

Comment: Alas, I don't believe it is supported:  

$ conda info mayavi | grep python 

only shows python 2.7*

I tried the option you suggested, and got the same results.

Comment: The https://anaconda.org/search?q=mayavi did the job for me (today, 27-12-2018). Mayavi 4.6.2 is available and works with python 3.6.7. So python 2.7 is not a necessity anymore with Mayavi 4.6.2.

See https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mayavi.

Thanks Make42!

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can try:

If you have Visual Studio installed, and Python Native Development Tools installed.

In Anaconda3, you can get VTK7.1.x from clinicalgraphics

```
conda install -c clinicalgraphics vtk
```

Open up the VS20xx x64 Native Command Prompt, setting up PATH for python properly:
e.g. `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Anaconda3`

Then install mayavi using pip from source.

```
pip install mayavi
```

It compiles successfully with VS2017 and Python 3.6 in windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

conda install -c menpo mayavi=4.5.0

Answer (score -1):

I get similar problems, curious why this would be the case.  This is on Ubuntu 16.04; just downloaded the latest version of Anaconda.

> $ conda install -c anaconda mayavi=4.5.0 Fetching package metadata
>   ........... Solving package specifications: .
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>     - mayavi 4.5.0* -> pyqt 4.* -> python 2.6* -> openssl 1.0.1*
>     - python 3.6* Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package
>
> $ conda install -c menpo mayavi=4.5.0  Fetching package metadata
>   ........... Solving package specifications: .
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>     - mayavi 4.5.0* -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
>     - python 3.6* Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

Doing a 'conda info mayavi' shows no versions for Python 3 and up.

What is the best procedure for installing a package when conda won't do the trick?

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question, not as giving an answer. This site is not like a forum ;-).